# Slack `member_joined_channel` - how to check if my bot was invited?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to send a message to any public channel that my bot gets added to. I notice there's the `member_joined_channel` event as documentated [here](https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel), however I'm not sure how to figure out when to determine if **my bot** was the invited member. I know there's the `user` property, but I don't want to hardcode my bot's user ID.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a WebSocket-based "RTM" bot, you can listen for the `channel_joined` [event](https://api.slack.com/events/channel_joined), which is sent only for your own user/bot.

For the more typical Webhook-based bot, the best choice is to listen for the `member_joined_channel` [event](https://api.slack.com/events/member_joined_channel) and compare the `user` field if you want an event-based implementation. *Hardcoding* or otherwise storing your bot's user id is a necessity.

Otherwise, as suggested in the previous answer, you can periodically query all conversations with the `conversations.list` [method](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list) and check if you have become a member using the `is_member` field.

In case one of these methods does not provide the `is_private` field that you need to determine whether a channel is public, you can use the `conversations.info` [method](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info), which returns a `channel` object with the `is_private` field.

Answer (score 1):

Coversation info is your friend https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the slack API, but i found this endpoint :
https://api.slack.com/types/conversation

In the response, you have a flag `is_member` which contains what you need I think :

> is_member indicates whether the user, bot user or Slack app associated
> with the token making the API call is itself a member of the
> conversation.

EDIT:
then, you can retreive the list of public channel and have this flag on every channel accessible :
https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list